# Typed.js en Angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Estoy intentando agregar la libreria de Typed.js en Angular.
https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/

Sin embargo, no he encontrado la forma de hacerlo funcionar...
Primero, me dice que tengo que hacer el import en mi componente,

```
import Typed from 'typed.js';
```

Posteriomente hacer la funcion

```
    var options = {
      strings: ["<i>First</i> sentence.", "&amp; a second sentence."],
      typeSpeed: 40
    }

var typed = new Typed(".element", options);
```

Que intente, desde un main.js en mi carpeta assets, y tambien desde app.component.ts pero no funciono.
¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar, o tambien, alguna alternativa bien funcional en Angular?

Tenia una plantilla HTML,CSS,JS con dicha libreria, pero no pude hacerla funcionar correctamente en Angular, enlace los archivos desde el angular.json pero no funcionaba el efecto de "typed"

Comment: mira esta respuesta, en mi caso funcionó con angular 12
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085213/how-to-integrate-typed-js-with-angular-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes crear una Directiva Angular y enviar la referencia del ElementoHtml como primer parametro para que Typed.js lo reconozca, algo asi:

```
    @Directive({
      selector: '[typedJs]'
    })
    export class TypedJsDirective {

        constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const options = {
           strings: ["<i>First</i> sentence.", "&amp; a second sentence."],
           typeSpeed: 40
        }

        const typed = new Typed(this.elementRef.nativeElement, options);
    }
```

luego podras usar la directiva en cualquier parte del proyecto usando `<any [typedJs]>...</any>`